# CSS/SCSS - value depends on selector

Tags: css, sass

With an accordion each level having a incrementing margin as it goes deeper:

```
Level 1A
  Level 2
    Level 3
      Level 4
Level 1B
...
```

CSS:

```
.level1 {
  margin: 1em;
}
.level2 {
  margin: 3em;
}
.level3 {
  margin: 5em;
}
...
```

Is there CSS/SCSS syntax like:

```
.level[n] {
  margin: (2n-1)em
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SASS/SCSS you can create for loops and generate the necessary amount of classes.

SASS:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4
  .level#{$i}
    margin: (2 * $i - 1) * 1em
```

SCSS:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    .level#{$i} {
        margin: (2 * $i - 1) * 1em ;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is no pure CSS solution.